# Cannot send message to Instagram review user

Tags: instagram-api

I'm working on a unified inbox app that allows user to manage their Instagram messages and
I'm currently going through the review process to get the `instagram_manage_messages` permission for the Instagram Messaging API.

Our review failed because the reviewer could not send messages to their Instagram account.

We are making a POST request to the URL
`https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me/messages?access_token=...`
with this payload:

```
{
  "message": {
   "text": "..."
  }, 
  "recipient": {
    "id": "4287033....'
  }
}
```

Which results in a 400 with this error message:

```
{"error": {
  "message": "(#100) The action is invalid since it's not the thread owner.",
  "type":"OAuthException",
  "code":100,
  "error_subcode":2534037,
  "fbtrace_id":"..."
}}
```

I've verified that the `access_token` is a page access token with the appropriate scopes.

Sending messages to our own Instagram accounts which are connected to a Facebook user with a role on the app works as expected. Any pointers to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Using the token, I can fetch the conversation with the reviewer's user and the messages our system received.

Comment: How are you getting the access_token? According to the official [docs](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3322836/211174618-674906a9-c1da-4456-b170-ebca913f3ffe.png) and interpreting the error message, you are trying to read the messages from another user. This could be related to the login.

Comment: I _think_ that's not the issue, as I can fetch the conversation and messages. I've extended my question.

Comment: Could it be as simple as the end user is attempting to comment/reply on a thread that they do not have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread ownership is a concept of the [Handover Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/handover-protocol/), which enables two or more Facebook applications to participate in a conversation.

Apparently, our reviewer re-used the same conversation to test multiple applications, and one of the previously tested application retained control of the conversation.

We did not plan to support Handover Protocol, but it seems we have to at least handle this error gracefully.

On a side note, the search bar on the top on the developers.facebook.com does *not* search the bug reports. Explicitly searching the bug reports put me on the right track.